# Function app gives forbidden ip if private endpoint is connected

Tags: networking, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have a APIM that should call a function app. All is good and works, until i try to connect a private endpoint to the function app. Then i get denied access, Even though i have enabled all access to the function app through network.

I tried a trace, and i can reach the function app. However i get a x-ms-denied-ip.

THe apim and function app are both connected to different vnets, so it should go the public route.

IF i connect to the function app directly, it works fine. So it is some integration between apim and the function app that is wrong

Comment: Are you using the Premium Plan function app?

Comment: Did you by any chance not enable public access to function app? See step 5 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Comment: Hi! The issue was that service endpoints was enabled, so i had to enable access for the spesific subnet. It was confusing that all logs showed the public ip's or a ipv6 adress(web service endpoint uses ipv6, but it does not work if you allow-list this ip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that service endpoints was enabled, spesifically the web service.
This led to a ipv6 adress being the used adress, but it did not work when i allowed-listed this ip-adress. The solution was to allow-list the subnet that the apim was connected to.